# why after cloning a spring boot repo from github showing error "Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have created a spring boot Rest project I tested this on my system things were working fine.
Then I pushed the code to to [Github (Repo link)](https://github.com/animeshsgit/eventif/tree/master/Employee_Management_App/BackEnd/EMA)
Now after I cloned the repo on my another directory then done the import the "existing maven project" such that it can build. but now when I run the application I am getting following error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-30T11:06:31.614+05:30 ERROR 2060 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

not getting what the issue is here

Help is really appreciated !..
Thanks, happy coding

I have tried with some changes in `application.properties` file `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/project_managementapp`

but it didn't work out,
the expected behavior is that after cloning the project, it should run and APIs should work with the client

Comment: Just thinking. Shouldn't it be `${MYSQL_HOST}:localhost` ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How are you running the application? I'm not able to reproduce the error in your question.

Comment: @Karthikeyan
In eclipse I coded and then run as a Java application

Comment: Check that the application runs in the command prompt/terminal using `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: @Karthikeyan
I got some error

C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\anim\EMA>mvn spring-boot:run
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What about `mvnw spring-boot:run`

Comment: Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Comment: Seems like maven is not correctly installed/set up. You should definitely fix that

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I am using "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers" and it already has maven pre installed in it. As I have mentioned that earlier things were working fine but when I pushed to github and then cloned in another directory issue is coming there in new directory